Issues with Passing Form Action to Controller in Laravel
I'm new to Laravel and I'm trying to converting my codeigniter code into laravel, now am experiencing an issue with passing form actions to my controller.
When i clicked on Add Vehicle button it displays me a blank white page instead of form. I didn't get any error or something on the screen.. i don't know the exact reason of this problem..
Here is my code,
Route
use App\Http\Controllers\VehicleController;

Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/add-vehicle/add', [VehicleController::class, 'handleUsersVehicleData'])->name('add-vehicle.add');

Route::get('add', function(){
    return view('add_vehicle');
});

This is a Add Vehicle Button -
add_vehicle.blade.php (view file)
<button>
<a href="{{ route('add-vehicle.add') }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm rounded-pill">Add Vehicle</a>
</button>

Form -
new_vehicle_form.blade.php
@extends('layouts.auth') <!-- Adjust this to your layout -->

@section('content')
<div class="container-fluid">

    <!-- Page Heading -->
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-2 text-gray-800 fw-bold">Add Vehicle</h1>
    </div>

    <!-- DataTables Example -->
    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
        <div class="card-header py-3 mb-2">
            <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary fw-bold">Add New Vehicle</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            @if(session('status_message'))
                <div class="alert alert-info" id="status-message">{{ session('status_message') }}</div>
            @endif
            
            <!-- Form Starts -->
            <form id="saveForm" action="{{ route('add-vehicle.add') }}" method="POST" class="d-flex flex-column gap-3" novalidate>
                @csrf
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add"> <!-- Hidden input to specify action -->

                     {{-- other form inputs here --}}

                        @error('vehicle_number')
                            <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="align-self-center mt-3">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <a href="{{ url('/users-vehicle-data') }}">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ml-2">Back</button>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </form>
            <!-- Form Ends -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection


Controller -
VehicleController.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class VehicleController extends Controller
{
// Handle different actions for vehicle data
    public function handleUsersVehicleData(Request $request, $action, $id = null)
    {
         switch ($action) {
            case 'add':
                if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
                    // Handle form submission
                    $validated = $request->validate([
                        'new_user_id' => 'required|exists:register_form,id',
                        'vehicle_name' => 'required',
                        'vehicle_number' => ['required', 'regex:/^[A-Z]{2}\d{2}[A-Z]{2}\d{4}$/'],
                    ], [
                        'vehicle_number.regex' => 'Please enter a valid number in the format XX00XX0000.'
                    ]);
    
                    $user = DB::connection('mentor_db')->table('register_form')->where('id', $request->input('new_user_id'))->first();
                    if (!$user) {
                        return back()->withErrors(['status_message' => 'Failed to add - User doesn\'t exist!']);
                    }
    
                    DB::connection('mentor_db')->table('vehicle_data')->insert([
                        'user_name' => $user->user_name,
                        'user_id' => $request->input('new_user_id'),
                        'vehicle_name' => $request->input('vehicle_name'),
                        'vehicle_number' => $request->input('vehicle_number'),
                        'created_at' => now(),
                        'updated_at' => now(),
                    ]);
                    return back()->with('status_message', 'Added Successfully!');
                  
                } else {
                    // Handle GET request - Show form
                    $vehicles_name = DB::connection('mentor_db')->table('vehicle_data')->select('vehicle_name')->get();
                    return view('new_vehicle_form', $vehicles_name);
                }
                break;
    
        }
    }
  }

I checked the routes but still can't figure out the issue. When I tried debugging with dd(), I realized that the action isn't being passed to the controller. Obviously, that would cause the view file not to load.
However, I don't understand why the action isn't reaching the controller when I click the Add Vehicle button, it just displays a blank white page instead of form.

Also your route is wrong you take action params in method but you did not pass it from the route

Why did you use switch ($action) ? As per the request type you still can do your respective task without even using switch() .Also /add-vehicle/add is being treated as hard coded uri , $action in this case of no use.

@sandipbharadva so exactly what do i have to do? i m confused right now, before i thought the else condition in controller will handle the get method and then it will show the view..

@Subha Actually i have other 3, 4 different cases, which i omitted here to show the exact problem

@Manish you have to pass dynamic action from the route. Now please check laravel document for the routing.
It shows you blank screen because in controller not getting $action so it will not execute your switch case.

@Manish, above comment by "sandip" is correct. In route defination just change the uri into /add-vehicle/{add} and  your issue will be solved

@sandipbharadva yess thanks for help :) , it was a silly routing mistake

@Subha yess tysm :)

you have to pass dynamic action from the route. Now please check laravel document for the routing. It shows you blank screen because in controller not getting $action so it will not execute your switch case

please marked it as an answer if it works for you @Manish
